# Lisp, While function undefined error with CLISP?

Tags: loops, while-loop, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am working on a program in LISP, using CLISP to run the program.

My function has a while statement in it, but CLISP is returning

```
*** - EVAL: undefined function WHILE
```

Function is nothing fancy,

```
(defun heap-insert (heap item key)
  "Put an item into a heap. [Page 150 CL&R]."
  ;; Note that ITEM is the value to be inserted, and KEY is a function
  ;; that extracts the numeric value from the item.
  (vector-push-extend nil heap)
  (let ((i (- (length heap) 1))
    (val (funcall key item)))
    (while (and (> i 0) (>= (heap-val heap (heap-parent i) key) val))
      do (setf (aref heap i) (aref heap (heap-parent i))
               i (heap-parent i)))
        (setf (aref heap i) item)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed `loop` before your `while`

try:

```
(defun heap-insert (heap item key)
  "Put an item into a heap. [Page 150 CL&R]."
  ;; Note that ITEM is the value to be inserted, and KEY is a function
  ;; that extracts the numeric value from the item.
  (vector-push-extend nil heap)
  (let ((i (- (length heap) 1))
    (val (funcall key item)))
    (loop while (and (> i 0) (>= (heap-val heap (heap-parent i) key) val))
      do (setf (aref heap i) (aref heap (heap-parent i))
               i (heap-parent i)))
        (setf (aref heap i) item)))
```

Answer (score 5):

There's no function or macro (or "statement") with the name `while` in Common Lisp, so CLISP is right to give you that error message.

Maybe you meant to use the `loop` macro, which accepts `while` as part of its syntax.

Answer (score 5):

There is no standard `while` looping construct in Common Lisp, there is one in Emacs Lisp. However, if you want one, it is relatively simple to make that happen.

```
(defmacro while (condition &body body)
  `(loop while ,condition
      do (progn ,@body)))
```